# Strange error - custom module template calling by using {{block class="" name="" template="" }} not working

Tags: magento2.4.1, script

I am trying to call 3 the script on my cms page pagebuilder,

The thing is, first one only return the value, but i individually tested each values is working, if add at the same time three values first value only working, if add two scripts first only working, i mean which script first that is only working, remaining not working.

```
{{block class="Amasty\Storelocator\Block\Location" name="location.block.address" template="Zero_Storelocator::home-page-mobile1.phtml" }}
{{block class="Amasty\Storelocator\Block\Location" name="location.block.mobile" template="Zero_Storelocator::home-page-mobile2.phtml" }}
{{block class="Amasty\Storelocator\Block\Location" name="location.block.hours" template="Zero_Storelocator::home-page-mobile3.phtml" }}
```

[image]

Comment: Not getting your issue properly.

Comment: 1) I want to get three values 2) i am using {{block class="Amasty\Storelocator\Block\Location" name="location.block.address" template="Zero_Storelocator::home-page-mobile1.phtml" }}

Comment: If add only one values on cms page page builder the value is return.

Comment: If i add three values 1) {{block class="Amasty\Storelocator\Block\Location" name="location.block.address" template="Zero_Storelocator::home-page-mobile1.phtml" }}
2) {{block class="Amasty\Storelocator\Block\Location" name="location.block.mobile" template="Zero_Storelocator::home-page-mobile2.phtml" }}
3) {{block class="Amasty\Storelocator\Block\Location" name="location.block.hours" template="Zero_Storelocator::home-page-mobile3.phtml" }}

Comment: If i add three values first value only return the values, remaining not return the values, FYI i tested individually all values return the values, if i add three script at the same time first script only return the values.

Comment: Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/spNzo.png   first value only return the value, second and third values not return, if i add second and third script, second script only return the values third script not return.

Comment: which script is first, that one script only returns the values, remaining not return the values.

Comment: Which page builder extension you are using?

Comment: really strange, i can't understand, in my localhost its working when i move to live site i am getting an error.

Comment: I am using the commerce edition page builder inbuild.

Comment: Have you tried by disabling page builder extension on live website?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123334/discussion-between-zus-and-zealousweb).

Comment: Impossible bro, we are design most of the pages using pagebuilder.

Comment: In localhost i am using pagebuilder, its working good. live only i am getting the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123343/discussion-between-zus-and-zealousweb).

Comment: Still values not return, any help thanks.